# Why 'IN' in mySQL does not filter data correctly?

Tags: mysql, select

I am using the following query to get RegionIDs for a given listingID and UserID. But my result includes ListingIDs that I did not expect but still belongs to the User.

```
SET @ListingID = 71;
SET @UserID = 160;

SELECT 
LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID,
LIST_REGION_REGION_ID,
REGION_NICK_NAME
FROM 
listing_region
INNER JOIN region ON REGION_ID = LIST_REGION_REGION_ID AND REGION_USER_ID = @UserID
WHERE LIST_REGION_REGION_ID IN (SELECT LIST_REGION_REGION_ID FROM listing_region WHERE LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID = @ListingID);
```

Results : 
[image]

Why am I getting ListingID 58 that I did not request in my query ?

Comment: You're getting it because it satisfied the conditions you passed to the query. Also, you don't need `IN` and a subquery, simple `WHERE LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID = @ListingID` would suffice.

Comment: Because you’re asking for all rows that match the LIST_REGION_REGION_ID and there probably are multiple. You’ll need to explain exactly what you want to get as result

Comment: I am specifically asking "SELECT LIST_REGION_REGION_ID FROM listing_region WHERE LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID = @ListingID". So why the sub query results in extra ListingID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID 58 because in the sub query, you get all the LIST_REGION_REGION_ID that have the LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID=71. In your results you can see that tou get LIST_REGION_REGION_ID numbers 11 and 12.

So your WHERE clause looks like this

```
WHERE LIST_REGION_REGION_ID IN (11,12)
```

and that includes the row with the LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID=58

You can do the query without the sub query:

```
SET @ListingID = 71;
SET @UserID = 160;

SELECT 
    LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID,
    LIST_REGION_REGION_ID,
    REGION_NICK_NAME
FROM 
    listing_region
INNER JOIN region ON REGION_ID = LIST_REGION_REGION_ID AND REGION_USER_ID = @UserID
WHERE  listing_region.LIST_REGION_LISTING_ID = @ListingID;
```